# Simple dice console game in C#

Tags: c#, object-oriented, .net, console, dice

I wrote a little console game that is supposed to take some dice and some players and determine the winner of the game. I wrote it for the sole purpose of figuring out why i'm doing the things i'm doing and to better my skills. This way when I move onto learning a new language I can use this game as a guidance tool. I'd love some feedback on what could be done to improve this/make it more readable/if you see any errors/any standards that i'm missing/ misusing anything/ bad OOP especially. Even if something isn't done wrong but there is a better way to do it that would be great.

I didn't comment on purpose because it's not incredibly complicated and that would add a hundred lines.

Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Dice Game..." + Environment.NewLine);

        return Game.Setup();

    }
}
```

Game.cs

```
public static class Game
{

    public static List<Player> Players;
    public static List<Die> Dice;
    public static List<string> ComputerNames = new List<string> { "Herold", "Juan", "Jack", "Dodson", "Watson", "Tom", "Jillian", "Sarah", "Leonardo", "Jane" };

    public static int Setup()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start. Press Q to Quit.");

        string start = string.Empty;
        while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(start))
        {
            start = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        if (start != "q" && start != "Q")
        {
            Start();
        }

        return Quit();
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        Dice = new List<Die>();
        Settings.GetSettingsFromUser();
        GetPlayers();
        DisplayPlayers();
        Begin(Players);
        Setup();
    }

    public static int Quit()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    private static void GetPlayers()
    {
        Players = new List<Player>();

        for(int i = 1; i <= Settings.NumberOfHumanPlayers; i++)
        {
            Player player = new Player(i);
            Players.Add(player);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= Settings.NumberOfAIPlayers; i++)
        {
            Player player = new Player(i + Settings.NumberOfHumanPlayers, isAi: true);
            Players.Add(player);
        }
    }

    public static void DisplayPlayers()
    {
        Debug.Assert(Players != null && Players.Count >= 2);

        Console.WriteLine("Players in the game...");

        foreach(Player p in Players)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.PlayerNumber + ". " + p.Name);
        }
    }

    public static void Begin(List<Player> players)
    {
        Debug.Assert(Players != null && Players.Count >= 2);
        Debug.Assert(Dice != null && Dice.Count > 0);

        for (int i = 1; i <= Settings.NumberOfRounds; i++)
        {
            foreach (Player p in players)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Player " + p.PlayerNumber + "(" + p.Name + ") " + "roll... (Press enter to roll)");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Player " + p.PlayerNumber + "(" + p.Name + ") " + "rolled a " + p.RollDice() + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            GetRoundWinner(players);
        }
        GetWinner();
    }

    private static void GetRoundWinner(List<Player> players)
    {
        if (Settings.HighScoreWins)
        {
            GetHighScoreWinner(players);
        }
        else
        {
            GetLowScoreWinner(players);
        }
    }

    private static void GetHighScoreWinner(List<Player> players)
    {
        int maxScore = 0;
        List<Player> winners = new List<Player>();
        foreach (Player p in players)
        {
            if (p.RoundScore >= maxScore)
            {
                maxScore = p.RoundScore;
            }
        }

        foreach (Player p in players)
        {
            if (p.RoundScore == maxScore)
            {
                winners.Add(p);
            }
        }

        if (winners.Count > 1)
        {
            Begin(winners);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Player p in Game.Players)
            {
                if (winners.First().PlayerNumber == p.PlayerNumber)
                {
                    p.AddWin();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void GetLowScoreWinner(List<Player> players)
    {
        int minScore = int.MaxValue;
        List<Player> winners = new List<Player>();
        foreach (Player p in players)
        {
            if (p.RoundScore <= minScore)
            {
                minScore = p.RoundScore;
            }
        }

        foreach (Player p in players)
        {
            if (p.RoundScore == minScore)
            {
                winners.Add(p);
            }
        }

        if (winners.Count > 1)
        {
            Begin(winners);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Player p in Game.Players)
            {
                if (winners.First().PlayerNumber == p.PlayerNumber)
                {
                    p.AddWin();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void GetWinner()
    {
        int maxWins = 0;
        List<Player> winners = new List<Player>();

        foreach(Player p in Game.Players)
        {
            if(p.Wins >= maxWins)
            {
                maxWins = p.Wins;
            }
        }

        foreach (Player p in Game.Players)
        {
            if (p.Wins == maxWins)
            {
                winners.Add(p);
            }
        }

        if(winners.Count == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Player " + winners.First().PlayerNumber + "(" + winners.First().Name + ") won!!!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Tie!");
            Console.Write("Players ");
            foreach(Player p in winners)
            {
                if(winners.Last() == p)
                {
                    Console.Write(p.PlayerNumber + "(" + p.Name + ") ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(p.PlayerNumber + "(" + p.Name + "), ");
                }

            }
            Console.Write("Tied!");
        }
        Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Settings.cs

```
public static class Settings
{
    public static bool HighScoreWins { get; set; } = true;
    public static int NumberOfRounds { get; set; } = 1;
    public static int NumberOfHumanPlayers { get; set; }
    public static int NumberOfAIPlayers { get; set; }

    public static void GetSettingsFromUser()
    {
        GetGameType();
        GetDice();
        GetNumberOfRounds();
        GetNumberOfHumanPlayers();
        GetNumberOfAIPlayers();            
    }

    private static void GetGameType()
    {
        string gameType = string.Empty;

        while (gameType != "H" && gameType != "h" && gameType != "L" && gameType != "l")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("High(H) or Low(L)?");
            gameType = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        if(gameType == "H" || gameType == "h")
        {
            HighScoreWins = true;
        }
        else
        {
            HighScoreWins = false;
        }
    }

    private static void GetDice()
    {
        int numberOfDice = 0;
        while (numberOfDice <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How many dice?");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfDice);
        }

        bool playStandard = false;

        Console.WriteLine("Play with standard 6 sided dice? (y)");
        string stdDiceInput = Console.ReadLine();
        if(stdDiceInput == "y" || stdDiceInput == "Y")
        {
            playStandard = true;
        }

        for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfDice; i++)
        {
            Die die;
            if (playStandard)
            {
                die = new Die();
            }
            else
            {
                int numberOfSides = 0;
                while (numberOfSides <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("How many sides on die " + i + "?");
                    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfSides);
                }
                die = new Die(numberOfSides);
            }
            Game.Dice.Add(die);
        }
    }

    private static void GetNumberOfRounds()
    {
        int numberOfRounds = 0;
        while (numberOfRounds <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How many rounds?");
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfRounds))
            {
                NumberOfRounds = numberOfRounds;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void GetNumberOfHumanPlayers()
    {
        int numberOfHumanPlayers = 0;
        while (numberOfHumanPlayers <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How many human players?");
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfHumanPlayers))
            {
                NumberOfHumanPlayers = numberOfHumanPlayers;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void GetNumberOfAIPlayers()
    {
        int numberOfAIPlayers = 0;
        int minNumberOfAI = 0;

        if(NumberOfHumanPlayers == 1)
        {
            minNumberOfAI = 1;
        }
        if(NumberOfHumanPlayers == 0)
        {
            minNumberOfAI = 2;
        }

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How many computer opponents?");
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfAIPlayers))
            {
                NumberOfAIPlayers = numberOfAIPlayers;
            }

        }
        while (numberOfAIPlayers < minNumberOfAI || numberOfAIPlayers > Game.ComputerNames.Count);
    }
}
```

Player.cs

```
public class Player
{
    public Player(int playerNumber, bool isAi = false)
    {
        PlayerNumber = playerNumber;
        if (isAi)
        {
            IsAI = true;
            GenerateAIName();
        }
        else
        {
            RequestPlayerName();
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Wins { get; set; }
    public bool IsAI { get; set; }
    public int RoundScore { get; set; }
    public int PlayerNumber { get; set; }        

    private void RequestPlayerName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is the " + PlayerNumber + " players name?");
        Name = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private void GenerateAIName()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
        {
            int index = rand.Next(1, Game.ComputerNames.Count);
            if (Game.Players.Where(x => x.Name == Game.ComputerNames[index]).FirstOrDefault() == null)
            {
                Name = Game.ComputerNames[index];
            } 
        }           
    }

    public void AddWin()
    {
        Wins++;
    }

    public int RollDice()
    {
        int rollScore = 0;
        foreach(Die die in Game.Dice)
        {
            rollScore += die.Roll();
        }
        RoundScore = rollScore;
        return rollScore;
    }
}
```

Die.cs

```
public class Die
{
    public Die(int numberOfSides = 6)
    {
        this.NumberOfSides = numberOfSides;
    }

    public int NumberOfSides { get; set; }

    public int Roll()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        return rand.Next(1, NumberOfSides + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your static classes `Game` and `Settings` contain *static state*. In general it is not good and should be avoided. I recommend remove static keyword from these classes definitions and add `Instance` field/property to them. So `Game` and `Settings` will be singletons.

You have some difficulties with `bool`s. This code

> ```
> if(gameType == "H" || gameType == "h")
> {
>     HighScoreWins = true;
> }
> else
> {
>     HighScoreWins = false;
> }
> ```

can be replaced with

```
HighScoreWins = gameType == "H" || gameType == "h";
```

This code

> ```
> bool playStandard = false;
>
> Console.WriteLine("Play with standard 6 sided dice? (y)");
> string stdDiceInput = Console.ReadLine();
> if(stdDiceInput == "y" || stdDiceInput == "Y")
> {
>     playStandard = true;
> }
> ```

can be replaced with

```
Console.WriteLine("Play with standard 6 sided dice? (y)");
string stdDiceInput = Console.ReadLine();
var playStandard = stdDiceInput == "y" || stdDiceInput == "Y";
```

This large code

> ```
> int maxWins = 0;
> List<Player> winners = new List<Player>();
>
> foreach(Player p in Game.Players)
> {
>     if(p.Wins >= maxWins)
>     {
>         maxWins = p.Wins;
>     }
> }
>
> foreach (Player p in Game.Players)
> {
>     if (p.Wins == maxWins)
>     {
>         winners.Add(p);
>     }
> }
> ```

can be rewritten as

```
var players = Game.Players;

var maxWins = players.Select(p => p.Wins).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max();
var winners = players.Where(p => p.Wins == maxWins).ToList();
```

This loop

> ```
> int rollScore = 0;
> foreach(Die die in Game.Dice)
> {
>     rollScore += die.Roll();
> }
> ```

can be replaced with

```
var rollScore = Game.Dice.Sum(d => d.Roll());
```

Comment: Ahhh yes, all of the boolean detail is awesome, thank you for that. I was actually curious about making everything static when I started building this though. Because I thought the reason something should be static is that it would be used throughout the entire life while the app ran. I figured game would at least be a good fit for that, or no?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new random in each call is bad.  On quick calls could get the same `seed` and Next.

```
public class Die
{
    Random rand;
    public Die(int numberOfSides = 6)
    {
        this.NumberOfSides = numberOfSides;
    }    
    public int NumberOfSides { get; set; }
    public int Roll()
    {
        return rand.Next(1, NumberOfSides + 1);
    }
    public Die (Random Rand)
    {
       rand = Rand;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that it would create the same seed and next. Why and how can that happen?

Comment: Because it can get the same seed.  Spin up 100 new Random in a loop and get the first 10 new and see for yourself.

Comment: @Mash See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx#Multiple

Comment: ahh awesome, it uses the system clock to generate a seed on the default constructor. Thanks a ton for putting me on that!

Comment: I just earned close vote privilege.  After that not really many privileges I care about.